# Ruby MRI vs JRuby deployments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

My large Rails 4 web application currently uses JRuby hosted on Cloud Foundry (with a Tomcat server I believe).

- Ruby on Rails 4.1.4
- Ruby version 2.0.0-p195

The reasons for using JRuby were that since we use SQL Server as our DB, the sql server adapter gem was not ready for use - but it seems it is ready to be used now.  We currently use the JBDC driver to use SQL Server.

Deployments use Bamboo, which executes our Unit tests, and uses warbler to build a 100MB WAR file which is then deployed to cloud foundry.

I would like to know:

1. What advantages would be gained by moving to the MRI?  It would simplify the app since we have different gems for JRuby but we develop locally using the MRI on windows.  But what other advantages (if any)?
2. How would deployments differ in Bamboo on the native MRI? Would it be quicker to deploy? File size reduced?  Use a gem like Capistrano, can it be done in Bamboo?
3. How would the Cloud Foundry environment have to change to support MRI?

I am really knew to all this so I'm just looking to determine the advantages and disadvantages and whether its worth the effort..

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to move *away* from JRuby? Other than startup time, it's a *really* good runtime. You can do MRI-style JRuby deployments without building gigantic WARs.

Comment: My goal is to reduce deployment time, our unit tests take 20 mins to run.  We then run the release to create the WAR file, takes about 5 mins.  Then the deployment takes about 3 mins.  I am looking at ways to reduce these overall.  Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I'd start by profiling your test suite and figuring out why it's slow - you may not benefit from a runtime change depending on why it's slow. For deployments, you might look at a more typical Ruby deployment setup with Capistrano or whatnot, which just checks out the latest version of your source repo and reloads the app. That would prevent having to rebuild giant WARs all the time. I can't comment on CloudFoundry. You might look at using the `--dev` flag for your rake tasks and whatnot - it should improve jruby startup time. See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time

Comment: whats the best way to profile RSpec tests?  I tried quickly using parallel tests which reduced time, but most of the tests failed.  We have 2500+ tests.

Comment: `rspec -p` should give you a list of your slowest tests. For profiling specific tests I like https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/rspec-prof